# Выборка данных в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

| ID | Index_Group | Index_Left | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.235294 | 0.786379 | 1 |
| 2 | 0.3157 | 0.704742 | 0.333333 |
| 3 | 0.384615 | 1.829067 | 0.6 |
| 5 | 0.25 | 1.92618 | 1 |
| 7 | 0.66666666 | 12.776826 | 1 |

Есть таблица с группами.
Так же есть функция, в которую подаются 2 значения для выборки (по 3 и 4 колонке). По заданию выбирается группа, отвечающая последовательно следующим критериям:

1. Максимальное значение по **Index_Group**
2. **Index_Left** не больше заданного пользователем. В случае, если для максимального значения из 1го пункта Index_Left превышает заданный пользователем, брать следующую по Index_Group группу.
3. Percent не более заданного пользователем. В случае, если для выбранной по предыдущим пунктам группы процент превышает установленный пользователем, берется следующая по индексу(Index_Group) группа, которая удовлетворяет так же 2му критерию.

Вот такая вот выборка... Сам сделал просто через `WHERE Index_Left <= x AND Index_Left <= y` Ну и потом сортировка по индекс_груп и LIMIT 1. Для **x = 0.7** и **y = 3** получаю ID группы 3, но по чек листу должна выбраться 2я группа. Вообще странное условия из 3х последовательных критериев, что они должны выполняться как бы последовательно, в моем "решении" же будто наоборот снизу вверх.

Comment: По-моему, у вас путаница с условиями. В условиях 2 и 3 нужно сравнивать `Index_Left ` и `Percent` с числами, заданными пользователем, а вы сравниваете в запросе `Index_Group <= x AND Index_Left <= y`. Также непонятно, с какими именно полями должны корреспондировать x и y

Comment: Если применить x и y к подходящим, на мой взгляд, полям, то отбирается 2 группа: [демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6c4987/4)

Comment: В условии "3. Percent не более заданного пользователем", а в запросе `AND Index_Left <= y`. Должно быть `AND Percent <= y`